# digikam - error while loading shared libraries: libcudart.so.8.0

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, cuda, digikam

When I launch digikam I get an error about a `cuda` missing library (this is happening since I removed `cuda` more or less cleanly to solve something else):

```
hippo@hippo-camp:~$ digikam<BR>
digikam: error while loading shared libraries: libcudart.so.8.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory<BR>
hippo@hippo-camp:~$ which digikam<BR>
/usr/bin/digikam<BR>
hippo@hippo-camp:~$ lddtree /usr/bin/digikam<BR>
digikam => /usr/bin/digikam (interpreter => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2)<BR>
-     libdigikamgui.so.5.6.0 => /usr/lib/digikam/libdigikamgui.so.5.6.0<BR>
--        libopencv_core.so.3.2 => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so.3.2      
---             libcudart.so.8.0 => not found
```

as you can see `libcudart` is a dependency of `opencv`. I think it is linked to the face recognition feature which I don't really need.

How can I fix this? is there a way to install just the lib?

I have tried to reinstall `cuda` from scratch but it only gives me version 9 or 10. And I cannot reinstall version 8 from NVIDIA site because I am now in 18.04.3 LTS and it is only supported on version 16.04.

I have tried `--purge` and reinstall `digikam` but it does not fix the problem.

```
sudo apt-get install libopencv-dev python3-opencv --reinstall
```

did not solve it neither.

EDIT: the library is not anymore on this machine and I don't have a `cuda-8` directory anywhere.

How can I fix this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing appropriate version of CUDA in your distribution and create symbolic link:

1. Install CUDA.
2. Locate `libcudart.so`:

   ```
   sudo find / -type f -iname "libcudart.so*"
   ```
3. Create symbolic link:

   ```
   sudo ln -s [located place] /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudart.so.8.0
   ```

   **Put in [located place] the output of second step**

Hope this helps...

Comment: Have to use --override, even with this option I get: Driver:   Not Selected / Toolkit:  Installation Failed / Samples:  Not Selected
Logfile is /tmp/cuda_install_18660.log

Comment: in the log:  Can't locate InstallUtils.pm in @INC (you may need to install the InstallUtils module) (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.26.1 /usr/local/share/perl/5.26.1 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.26 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.26 /usr/share/perl/5.26 /usr/local/lib/site_perl /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base) at ./install-linux.pl line 6.

Comment: @wotter, it seems runfile is also not compatible, I will edit the answer.

Comment: option 2 makes sense, I'll give it a try (not fan of option 1, I'd rather use apt so I can purge later but I see no anaconda package)

Comment: sudo ln -s /usr/local/cuda-10.2/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcudart.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudart.so.8.0 did the trick, thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

If you have not **forced/bad-removed** cuda package and you cannot start digikam, then this is a bug!
*And I suggest you to open an issue in the bug tracker.*

If `digikam` does not start because it requires that *lib*, some package (digikam itself or any of its dependencies) is missing *lib*.

---

If you want `digikam` without that dependency, you can try to compile it by yourself disabling **(if it can be!)** the feature which requires `cuda`.

Comment: ok, I'll give a try to a report upstream

Comment: upstream does not consider this as a bug + the ubuntu package is an old version

Comment: @wotter I assumed it was latest version! And I agree with them if they reject the issue; Why do you use that version? Why don't you use latest? Update OP with these information

Comment: it is the latest version of the ubuntu package and this package contains an old version of digikam

Comment: Oh, probably I was wrong saying *upstream*! You have to report it in the Ubuntu bug-tracker since it's an issue related to compilation/packaging not to software itself

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it is not able to find library in path. You can try exporting path according to cuda libarary version installed.

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-8.0/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: the problem is that I don't have cuda8 anymore on this machine, question updated

Comment: upvoted too as it could have been the problem